# Recover Azure Databricks after deletion

Tags: azure, infrastructure

If Azure Databricks will be deleted by someone and which contains Notebooks as well. So, if we want to recover that databricks along with notebooks , is it possible?
If so please explain how we can achieve this type of condition.

Comment: When you say Databricks was deleted: Was your *cluster* deleted? If so, that doesn't matter, since notebooks are stored in the Databricks workspace. If the entire *workspace* was deleted, then you'd have to rely on either exports of your notebooks, or version control (Databricks notebooks may be integrated with both GitHub and Azure DevOps). If the workspace was deleted, and you don't have version control or exports of your notebooks, I can't imagine there's anything you can do at that point. Maybe contact support?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure Support issue (recovering a deleted resource); nothing that can be solved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to prevent deletion, you can set Azure Resource locks.  Specifically you can set the `CanNotDelete` lock.  This lock means authorized users can still read and modify a resource, but they can't delete the resource.

Some Azure services, such as Azure Databricks, use managed applications to implement the service. In that case, the service creates two resource groups. One resource group contains an overview of the service and isn't locked. The other resource group contains the infrastructure for the service and is locked.  **You should lock the resource containing the service to prevent accidental deletion**.

If you try to delete the infrastructure resource group, you get an error stating that the resource group is locked. If you try to delete the lock for the infrastructure resource group, you get an error stating that the lock can't be deleted because it's owned by a system application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources

Comment: I think the OP is talking about recovering notebooks from a deleted Databricks workspace, not configuring a workspace for deletion-avoidance...

Comment: If that's the case then the only thing I can think of is to open a support ticket to see if recovery is possible.